# Surrounding cents in <sup> tag using Rails number_to_currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I isolate cents and place them inside their own element? The output I'm looking for is this:

`<sup>$</sup>20<sup>99</sup>`

Notice there is no delimiter to separe the decimal units, and they're contained in their own `sup` tag. I know how to get `<sup>$</sup>20.99` when using `format: '<sup>%u</sup>%n'`, but this does not give me a way to isolate cents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to do it with substitution regex or something similar.

```
20.99.number_to_currency.sub(/\^([^\d]+)(\d+)([^\d]+)(\d+)/,     
'\1<sup>\2</sup>\3<sup>\4</sup>')
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. I almost wrote the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. This, however, means I'm unable to use internationalization, right?

Comment: I will edit the answer to capture the currency symbol and separator so you can use i18n.  AFAIK currency has some symbol/letter followed by a number, followed by a separator, followed by another number

Comment: @MichaelPapile the solution I just propose sort the I18n nicely I believe. Would you see any issue with it?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use this method, it allow me to support I18n properly but also to only use the `<sub>` container when I want the number displayed in HTML.

```
def formated_price(price, currency, options = {})
  html = options[:html].nil? ? false : options[:html]

  money = number_to_currency(price, unit: currency) || h('')
  if html
    separator = I18n.t('number.currency.format.separator')
    tmp = money.split(separator)
    tmp[1] = tmp[1].sub(/\A(\d+)(.*)\z/, content_tag(:sup, separator + '\1') + '\2') if tmp[1]
    money = tmp.join.html_safe
  end
  money
end
```

if you like your currency unit to be in `<sup>` as well when using HTML, you could use this instead:

```
def formated_price(price, currency, options = {})
  html = options[:html].nil? ? false : options[:html]
  if html
    money = number_to_currency(price, unit: content_tag(:sup, currency)) || h('')
    separator = I18n.t('number.currency.format.separator')
    tmp = money.split(separator)
    tmp[1] = tmp[1].sub(/\A(\d+)(.*)\z/, content_tag(:sup, separator + '\1') + '\2') if tmp[1]
    money = tmp.join.html_safe
  else
    number_to_currency(price, unit: currency) || h('')
  end
end
```

If you find any issue, please let me know.